# Tensorflow CIFAR10 example: GPUs not fully utilized

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm running the tensorflow example of CIFAR 10 (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) on a machine with 4x NVIDIA Titan X. I use the command

```
python cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py --num_gpus=4
```

However the GPUs are just used by 25%. Can somebody explain what the bottleneck is and how I can fix it? Are the input pipelines and the data transfer from the CPU to GPU the problem?

Comment: FYI [Why doesn't training RNNs use 100% of the GPU?](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/14403/843) and [Monitoring PCI Express bus usage](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/36676/903)

Answer (score 1):

That model from the CIFAR10 tutorial is very small so you're probably seeing a lot of overhead. You can have a look if increasing the batch size works to increase utilization, but I'd have a look at bigger data/models if I wanted to benchmark multi-GPU things.